# Visual studio temp folder access denied error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, access-denied, temp

I am trying to add a new file into a project in another computer in local network using Visual Studio 2010 and it throws temp folder "Access Denied" error.. All the temp folders (Windows and Users) has full write access available.. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Please see the error
[image]

Comment: It seems a bit odd that the *source* of a file copy is a temporary directory. And the file name it's complaining about includes a folder which doesn't agree with the full path quoted. One long shot - check the source file is not read only

Comment: Do you (or the process running) have access to write into the target directory?